# « Entre » ou « avec » dans « Que s’est-il passé… »

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Que s’est-il passé

…entre Johnny et Carole, quel était le motif de leur altercation?

…avec Johnny et Carole, quel était le sujet de leur prise de bec?

Si d’autres tournures vous viennent à l’esprit, n’hésitez pas à me les faire connaître.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On dira ***avec*** s'il y a une seule personne :

> Que s'est-il passé avec Carole ?

Quand il y a deux personnes, on peut aussi utiliser ***avec*** mais ***entre** / **et*** est plus précis. On indique bien que c'est entre les deux protagonistes et pas avec un éventuel tiers que quelque chose s'est passé.

Voici une tournure plus naturelle pour moi :

> Il s'est passé quoi entre Johnny et Carole ? C'est quoi l'embrouille entre eux ?

Answer (score 0):

Dans la réponse qui suit j'ai essayé de donner des indications justifiant ou non l'utilisation de « avec », mais l'ensemble qui résulte est assez rébarbatif et ne constitue pas un exposé très net de raisons évidentes, lesquelles peuvent  toujours  ne pas  être très bien  définies ; il est donc utile d'avertir le lecteur que si l'explication lui semble obscure trop longtemps, il est peut-être plus utile pour lui de ne pas insister.

« Avec », dans cette seconde construction, dépasse les limites acceptées auxquelles cette préposition reste bien définie.  Dans une liste donnée au [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avec),  des cinq  possibilités usuelles que comprend celle-ci,  seulement la seconde (expression initiale, ci-dessous) pourrait convenir, mais en fait ce n'est pas le cas.

> **3.** **[Indique la présence simultanée d'éléments formant contraste, la restriction, l'oppos.]**
> − **En dépit de, malgré.**
> • Avec tout le respect que je vous dois... (Ac.1932)
> • olga. − Va-t'en. hugo. − Non. Imitant Olga. « Je ferai ce que le parti me commandera. » Tu auras des surprises. Avec la meilleure volonté du monde, ce qu'on fait, ce n'est jamais ce que le parti vous commande. Sartre, Les Mains sales,1948, 1ertabl. 1, p. 22.
> − **En ce qui concerne (qqn), quand on a affaire à (qqn)**
> • Avec ce gaillard-là, on ne sait jamais à quoi s'en tenir. Pt Rob.
> − **Si l'on s'en rapporte à (qqn)**
> • Avec vous, avec lui, il n'y a jamais rien de bien fait. Ac.1932.
> **4**  **[Sert à marquer la cause. Souvent placé en tête de phrase dans ce cas]**
> − **Étant donné, en raison de**
> • Avec le temps qu'il fait, je préfère ne pas sortir. Lar. Lang. fr.
> − **Eu égard à**
> • Avec son orgueil, comment aurait-il pu accepter une récompense aussi modeste? Ac. Can.-Fr.1968.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/concerner)) **B.** − Loc. prép. **En/pour ce qui concerne qqn ou qqc.** *Pour ce qui est de, quant à*.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quant%20%C3%A0)) **quant à** **A.** − Loc. prép.
> **1.** [Marque la sélection thématique parmi les éléments d'un parad.] Pour ce qui est de, en ce qui concerne. Synon. pour, à l'égard de, (au sujet) de, relativement à, à propos de.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/paradigme))  **paradigme** **B.** − LING. Ensemble des unités d'un certain type apparaissant dans un même contexte et qui sont de ce fait dans un rapport d'opposition, de substituabilité (p.oppos. à syntagme).

- *en ce qui concerne* Johnny et Carole, quel était le sujet de leur prise de bec?
- *pour* Johnny et Carole, quel était le sujet de leur prise de bec? (*Le propos va traiter d'un fait déjà abordé.*)
- *à propos de* Johnny et Carole, quel était le sujet de leur prise de bec? (*Le propos va traiter d'un fait déjà abordé.*)

Il semble que l'on néglige le contexte d'utilisation de « avec » ou, ce qui est pareil, de « en ce qui concerne » : la présence  simultanée d'éléments formant contraste, la restriction, l'opposition, reste nécessaire, or il n'y a aucun élément autre que l'élément « Johnny et Carole », et de plus, s'il y en a un, mettons Pierre et Paul, le sujet en rapport avec lequel on réfère à Johnny et Carole ne peut pas impliquer un contraste vis-à-vis d'un sujet de nature apparentée en ce qui concerne Pierre et Paul et cet élément ne forme pas un contraste.  Ce sujet est la question de savoir la raison d'une altercation ; s'il avait été le déroulement particulier d'une altercation, alors « avec » aurait été justifiable.

- … avec Johnny et Carole une altercation naurait pas duré deux minutes (*contraste sur le plan des altercations*)
- … avec Johnny et Carole il n'y a pas de souci à se faire concernant la bonne marche de leur travail collectif (*sujet apparenté, la bonne entente*)

---

Une difficulté subsiste : « avec » et « en ce qui concerne » ne sont pas équivalents. En prenant deux exemples du [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_ce_qui_concerne) on se rend compte de ce fait rapidement.

> • Il se berçait d’illusions, car en réalité tout avait changé, mais le brave pasteur n’avait jamais fait preuve de clairvoyance et de psychologie **en ce qui concernait** ses filles. — (Marie Kuhlmann, Les Filles du pasteur Muller, Place des Éditeurs, 2010)
> • L’ajonc n’est pas inférieur aux autres engrais verts cultivés, au point de vue de l’acide phosphorique et de la potasse, et il leur est supérieur **en ce qui concerne** l’azote. — (Charles-Victor Garola, Engrais : Les matières fertilisantes, Paris : J.-B. Baillière & fils, 7e édition, 1925, page 193)

Dans la première phrase, « avec » est un remplacement possible mais pas exact parce qu'il a un effect restrictif en cela qu'on peut l'interpréter en tant que « quand il avait affaire à ». Dans la seconde, c'est une  préposition qui ne convient pas du tout. « Avec » ne signifie pas du tout « pour », et c'est cette préposition qui convient. Cela signifie que « en ce qui concerne Johnny et Carole … » est une possibilité non équivalente à « avec Johnny et Carole … » et dans laquelle il n'est plus question d'un contraste.

> ([découvrir le français](https://langue-francaise.tv5monde.com/decouvrir/dictionnaire/e/en%20ce%20qui%20concerne))  prp. à propos de, pour ce qui concerne, concernant, relativement à, touchant

---

- … quel était le motif de l'altercation entre Johnny et Carole ? (*Tout simple et (peut-être) banal*)